# Number of variables depends of last variable (5 Variables when last is false, 7 when last is true)

Tags: function, variables

I am trying to do function which can take different variables which depends of last one.
It should work like this:

```
$photo = new photo('slide', 'upload', 1000, 460, false);

function __construct ($nazwa, $katalog, $szerokosc, $wysokosc, $miniaturka)
```

And If last one is true I want to get 2 extra variables:

```
$photo = new photo('slide', 'upload', 1000, 460, true, 500, 230);

function __construct ($nazwa, $katalog, $szerokosc, $wysokosc, $miniaturka, $szerokosc_min, $wysokosc_min)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you use constuct that takes 7 variables with 2 optional.

```
function __construct ($nazwa, $katalog, $szerokosc, $wysokosc, $miniaturka, $szerokosc_min=0, $wysokosc_min"0){
     if $miniaturka == True{
      //Take the value of the last two variables
     }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works ;) I didn't know that it could be that simple ;)

Comment: I'm glad to help.-- However, make sure you are passing the two last params' values when the 5param is True, otherwise you will get 0 as value!. Good luck!